# Getting 4 Numbers (Steps) Between Two Given Numbers

Tags: php

I am trying to get `4`steps number between two given numbers by using this code

```
<?php

function getNums($num1, $num2){
$diff = $num2 -$num1;
$steps =[];

$steps[0] = $diff/4;
$steps[1] = $diff/2;
$steps[2] = round($num2/1.33333333333);
$steps[4] = $num2;

    foreach($steps as $step) {
    echo $step;
    echo "<br>";
   }
}
```

the code works fine when two givens are (0,100), as `getNums(0, 100);` returns:

```
25
50
75
100
```

but when the numbers are like `getNums(50, 100);` the output is like

```
12.5
25
75
100
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: What's wrong withthe results of the second example? The results seems correct. If the problem is the value of the first step (`12.5`) you might consider to round it.

Comment: @il_raffa The numbers are supposed to be between 50 and 100. `12.5` and `25` are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the results of your divisions to `$num1`.

```
function getNums($num1, $num2){
    $diff = $num2 -$num1;
    $steps =[
        round($num1 + $diff/4), 
        round($num1 + $diff/2), 
        round($num1 + $diff*.75), 
        $num2
    ];

    foreach($steps as $step) {
        echo $step;
        echo "<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, can you please also let me know if I want to use `return` in the `getNums()` how can I call and use them in the code?

Comment: and how would I get access to those? I mean if I want to echo out the second option or if I want to save them into a Temporary table how cab I do it?

Comment: `$nums = getNums(50, 100);` Then you can access `$nums[1]`, etc.

Comment: This is basic PHP coding, nothing special. If a function returns a value, you can store it into a variable with an assignment.